# How exactly does a Tesla coil primary winding transfer energy to the secondary winding?

Tags: electromagnetism, resonance, tesla-coil

We know that the Tesla coil has a low coupling coefficient so most of the energy is transferred by using electric resonance. How exactly does it transfer the energy? When the oscillating magnetic field induces in the primary, does it work same as a normal magnetic field, or is it different from the normal magnetic field?

What is the exact use of an oscillating magnetic field?

Comment: Atul Futane - if this question is answered you should take the small trouble of formally accepting one of the answers. [Please read this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to remind you how that is done.

Answer (score 1):

The TC is just like an ordinary transformer, but it doesn't have an iron core. At the time NT hadn't a HF power source, so he used a rotary spark to load the capacitor that caused the primary L and C to start oscillating at HF. Then he used the secondary circuit that has a matched resonating frequency. Since the impedance of a series LC circuit as a minimum value at resonance, the current is maximal at that point, so the power.

> does it work same as a normal magnetic field, or is it different from
> the normal magnetic field?

It can't work any different.

Answer (score 1):

> *How exactly does it transfer the energy?*

It transfers energy using magnetic induction. The fact that the coupling is small serves only to limit the energy transferred. And, the fact that the coupling is small allows the primary and secondary coils to have rather large resonant peaks at the same frequency.

Answer (score 0):

> We know that the Tesla coil has a low coupling coefficient so most of the energy is transferred by using electric resonance.

It has a large spacing between the primary and the high voltage end of the secondary for electrical insulation. This spacing means that the coupling coefficient ends up in the 0.1 to 0.2 region, rather than nearly 1.00 as in conventional cored transformers.

It's not 'transferred using electric resonance' as such, it's transferred using standard electromagnetism. However, resonance is necessary to transfer all the energy over a number of cycles.

> How exactly does it transfer the energy? When the oscillating magnetic field induces in the primary, does it work same as a normal magnetic field, or is it different from the normal magnetic field?
>
> What is the exact use of an oscillating magnetic field?

Qualitatively the same way as in a normal transformer. The change in magnetic field threading the secondary induces a voltage in it. The low coupling is another way of saying that only effectively 10% to 20% of the primary magnetic field threads the secondary.

The difference between a close-coupled cored transformer and a loose one like a Tesla Coil is like the difference between moving a swing with your feet on the ground, and 'pumping it up' by sitting on it.

With your feet on the ground, you can get hold of the swing and move it to anywhere you want. You and the swing frame are anchored to the ground, and you can apply as much force as you want. This is 100% coupling.

On the other hand, 'pumping it up' by sitting on it and moving your centre of gravity about is very weak coupling. Your movement from one position to the next will move the swing by at most a hand-span. You have to repeat this movement again and again at the right times to gradually build up the oscillation of the swing. Resonance allows this to happen, storing the energy from previous movements.

The Tesla primary is made resonant to give regularly spaced alternations in the magnetic field (pushes to the secondary). The secondary is tuned to resonate at the same frequency so that its amplitude can build up over a number of cycles.